# Why does js eventhandler defined in separate file run before the associated event occur

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have the following code, which works as intended

```
let userNameEl = document.querySelector("#username");
let startGameBtn = document.querySelector(".start-game");

startGameBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!userNameEl.value) {
        alert("Please enter player name");
    }
});
```

But when I define the eventhandler in a separate file, the result isn't what I intended

```
import * as Utils from "./utils.js";

let userNameEl = document.querySelector("#username");
let startGameBtn = document.querySelector(".start-game");

startGameBtn.addEventListener("click",Utils.validatePlayerName(userNameEl));
```

The logic of validatePlayerName is similar to that of the anonymous function of the first addEventListener, but the result is different. It looks like `Utils.validatePlayerName(userNameEl))` runs before click event is assigned.

Comment: In the second version, your code **calls** the function and passes the returned result to `.addEventListener()`.  This is a very common mistake.

Comment: Try `startGameBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){ Utils.validatePlayerName(userNameEl); } );`

Comment: Alternatively calling the function, you can bind variable `userNameEl` to your function, which then will be added as a parameter once it is called like that: `startGameBtn.addEventListener("click", Utils.validatePlayerName.bind(this, userNameEl));`

Comment: Thank you guys. I see my mistake now